could not compile stellar xdr
Compiling gix-credentials v0.24.0
Compiling soroban-spec-rust v20.5.0
Compiling itertools v0.10.5
error: could not compile stellar-xdr (lib)
Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: /home/param2004/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc --crate-name stellar_xdr --edition=2021 /home/param2004/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/stellar-xdr-20.1.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=63 --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="alloc"' --cfg 'feature="base64"' --cfg 'feature="cli"' --cfg 'feature="curr"' --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="hex"' --cfg 'feature="next"' --cfg 'feature="serde"' --cfg 'feature="serde_json"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=e2bd48e1224eb9e0 -C extra-filename=-e2bd48e1224eb9e0 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install2k9KBH/release/deps -C strip=debuginfo -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install2k9KBH/release/deps --extern base64=/tmp/cargo-install2k9KBH/release/deps/libbase64-c22e8d3276abb4c8.rmeta --extern clap=/tmp/cargo-install2k9KBH/release/deps/libclap-dbd0f606c6faf2b5.rmeta --extern escape_bytes=/tmp/cargo-install2k9KBH/release/deps/libescape_bytes-22875244d31960d0.rmeta --extern hex=/tmp/cargo-install2k9KBH/release/deps/libhex-fafd655e914e3227.rmeta --extern serde=/tmp/cargo-install2k9KBH/release/deps/libserde-7e0925e564e3dd9c.rmeta --extern serde_json=/tmp/cargo-install2k9KBH/release/deps/libserde_json-49dbb4eda1626794.rmeta --extern serde_with=/tmp/cargo-install2k9KBH/release/deps/libserde_with-2ec1cf1b1852a64e.rmeta --extern stellar_strkey=/tmp/cargo-install2k9KBH/release/deps/libstellar_strkey-9994be0ce7d72bd2.rmeta --extern thiserror=/tmp/cargo-install2k9KBH/release/deps/libthiserror-dec3833b02bd9188.rmeta --cap-lints allow (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile soroban-cli v20.3.4, intermediate artifacts can be found at /tmp/cargo-install2k9KBH.
To reuse those artifacts with a future compilation, set the environment variable CARGO_TARGET_DIR to that path.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
